# How to get data and calibration from Arduino "9 Axis Motion Shield"

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to get data from the Arduino "9 Axis Motion Shield" and I have no issues to connect it, however, when trying the example code, the calibration value is always 0 (low) and I only get zeros from all sensors. Is there a specific way to get into calibration mode? The readme from the github repo is not very clear.

I am using the library from arduino as well as the example codes. https://github.com/arduino-org/arduino-library-nine-axes-motion

The output from the Euler example code is:

Time: 3296ms  H: 0.00deg  R: 0.00deg P: 0.00deg  A: 0 M: 0 G: 0 S: 0

Time: 3316ms  H: 0.00deg  R: 0.00deg P: 0.00deg  A: 0 M: 0 G: 0 S: 0

Time: 3336ms  H: 0.00deg  R: 0.00deg P: 0.00deg  A: 0 M: 0 G: 0 S: 0

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/device-calibration the web is full of tutorials...

Comment: Thanks for the link. All the information refer to the adafruit sensor but not the arduino shield. I know that they are similar but the same... And I have difficulties finding information about the shield.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Bullock found the solution.
The library on github was coded for an older version of the shield. The github user "trullock" (Andrew Bullock) fixed the issue. You can find his solution in his repository: https://github.com/trullock/arduino-library-nine-axes-motion